# How do you find the roots of $f[x] = x^4 - (10000000 x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, roots

Just started a calculus course. Its been awhile since I've done any algebra. I used to be good at math, I just need some help to get started.

Comment: Can you think of way to factor and then that equal to zero and proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT: Simply take it as $f(x)=x^2(x^2-10^7)$. I think we can see our roots very clearly now

Answer (score 3):

We can write $f(x)=x^2*(x^2-10^7)$ and we want to find where $f(x)=0$. We can do this by finding $x$ such that either $(x^2-10^7)=0$ or $x^2=0$.